# Standard deviation computed incorrectly

Tags: java

I have written a program that generate twenty random int values and calculates the min, max, mean, and standard deviation. However, when I tried to compute the standard deviation it does not compute properly and I cant figure out why.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class RandomNumbers {
    
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        
        Random rand = new Random();
        
        int values[] = new int[20];
        
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            values[i] = (int)(Math.random()*(100-1+1)+1); }

        int min = values[0], max = values[0];
        double mean = 0, sum = values[0], stand = 0;
        
        for (int i = 1; i < 20; i++) {
            sum += values[i];
            if (values[i]<min)
                min = values[i];
            if (values[i]>max)
                max = values[i]; }
            
        mean = sum/20;
        double stand_Sum = 0;
            
        for (int x = 0; x < 20; x++) {
            stand_Sum+=(values[x]-mean)*(values[x]-mean); }
        
        System.out.println("Min:       " + min);
        System.out.println("Max:       " + max);
        System.out.println("Mean:      " + mean);
        System.out.println("Std Dev:   " + stand_Sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you need a square root somewhere to calculate the standard deviation, but I don't see one in the code. Could this be a problem?

Comment: Can you explain which formula you tried to implement for computing the standard deviation?

Comment: Use the appropriate [formula](https://www.cuemath.com/data/standard-deviation/).

Comment: Please have a look at the formula. You're missing dividing by the amount of data points and taking the square root.

Comment: btw you've declared `rand` but not used it, and used `Math.random()` instead. It's better to use `rand.nextInt`. Also, it's good practice declare your variables when you use them, not before. And use `values.length` instead of repeating `20`.

Answer (score 2):

You have to average the sum, and then square root it:

```
System.out.println("Std Dev:   " + Math.sqrt(stand_Sum/20));
```

Comment: I think it still needs a square root. I could be wrong

Comment: You are right! Without sqrt it would be variance

Comment: Good stuff. Not to be a backseat coder, but it's probably a good idea to use `values.length` instead of `20` too

Answer (score 0):

### Source to calculate standard deviation:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.io.PrintStream;

public class SD {
    static PrintStream out=System.out;  

    public static void main(String ... $) {

        Random rand = new Random();

        int values[] = new int[20];

        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            values[i] = (int)(Math.random()*(100-1+1)+1);
            //System.out.print(values[i]+" ");
        }
        System.out.println();

        int min = values[0], max = values[0];
        double mean = 0, sum = 0, stand = 0;
        //calculating sum, min and max values
        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            sum += values[i];
            if (values[i]<min)
                min = values[i];
            if (values[i]>max)
                max = values[i]; 
        }
        //calculating mean
        mean = sum/20;
        double stand_Sum = 0;

        for (int x = 0; x < values.length; x++) {
            //stand_Sum+=(values[x]-mean)*(values[x]-mean);
            stand_Sum+=Math.pow(Math.abs(values[x]-mean),2.0);

        }

        out.println("Min:       " + min);
        out.println("Max:       " + max);
        out.println("Mean:      " + mean);
        out.println("Std Dev:   " + Math.pow(stand_Sum/values.length,0.5));
    }
}
```

### output :

```
$ java SD

Min:       6
Max:       92
Mean:      51.9
Std Dev:   23.35358644833808
```